# why ereg("^\d{11}$",18311111111) is false?

Tags: php, regex, ereg

my code is:

```
<?php
    $phone = 18311111111;
    if(ereg("^\d{11}$",$phone)){
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }
?>
```

i get false? why?

Comment: Warning: `ereg` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `ereg` does not support `\d`, you need use `[0-9]` instead.

And `ereg` is **deprecated**, use `preg_match` instead, then you could use `\d`.

```
if(preg_match("/^\d{11}$/",$phone)){
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Woops, typo: derepcated=>deprecated

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you shouldn't use `ereg` (deprecated) nor `preg_match` for such a simple test; you can use `ctype_digit()`:

```
if (ctype_digit($phone)) {
    // $phone consists of only digits
} else {
    // non-digit characters were found in $phone
}
```